# Prepare Time Series for Machine Learning - Long to Wide Format

Tags: r

I have a data frame of time series data in a 'long' format where there is 1 row/observation per day.  I would like to transform this data into a 'wide' format. Each row/observation should have the time series value for the current date and the previous 2 days.

To provide a concrete example, I will use the Air Quality data available in R.  This is what my input data frame looks like.

```
> input <- airquality[1:4,c("Month", "Day", "Ozone")]
> input
  Month Day Ozone
1     5   1    41
2     5   2    36
3     5   3    12
4     5   4    18
```

I would like to transform this input so that it looks like the following.

```
output <- data.frame(Month = 5, Day = 1:4, Ozone=c(41,36,12,18), Ozone.Prev.1=c(NA,41,36,12), Ozone.Prev.2=c(NA,NA,41,36))
> output
  Month Day Ozone Ozone.Prev.1 Ozone.Prev.2
1     5   1    41           NA           NA
2     5   2    36           41           NA
3     5   3    12           36           41
4     5   4    18           12           36
```

Any suggestions on a nice, clean way to do this?  Many thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the `lag` function from `zoo`, but the following small function get's the trick done without using additional packages:

```
shift_vector = function(vec, n) c(rep(NA, n), head(vec, -n))
output = transform(input, prev_1 = shift_vector(Ozone, 1), 
                          prev_2 = shift_vector(Ozone, 2))
output
  Month Day Ozone prev_1 prev_2
1     5   1    41     NA     NA
2     5   2    36     41     NA
3     5   3    12     36     41
4     5   4    18     12     36
```