# How to prepare paneldata to machine learning in Python?

Tags: pandas

I have a panel data set/time series. I want to prepare the dataset for machine learning prediction next year's gcp. My data looks like this:

```
ID,year,age,area,debt_ratio,gcp
654001,2013,49,East,0.14,0
654001,2014,50,East,0.17,0
654001,2015,51,East,0.23,1
654001,2016,52,East,0.18,0
112089,2013,39,West,0.13,0
112089,2014,40,West,0.15,0
112089,2015,41,West,0.18,1
112089,2016,42,West,0.21,1
```

What I want is something like this:

```
ID,year,age,area,debt_ratio,gcp,gcp-1,gcp-2,gcp-3
654001,2013,49,East,0.14,0,NA,NA,NA
654001,2014,50,East,0.17,0,0,NA,NA
654001,2015,51,East,0.23,1,0,0,NA
654001,2016,52,East,0.18,0,1,0,0
112089,2013,39,West,0.13,0,NA,NA,NA
112089,2014,40,West,0.15,0,0,NA,NA
112089,2015,41,West,0.18,1,0,0,NA
112089,2016,42,West,0.21,1,1,0,0
```

I've tried Pandas melt function, but it didn't work out. I searched online and found this post that is exact what I want to do, but it is done in R:

```
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19813077/prepare-time-series-for-machine-learning-long-to-wide-format
```

Does anybody know how to do this in Python Pandas? Any suggestion would be appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`DataFrameGroupBy.shift`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.shift.html) in loop:

```
for i in range(1, 4):
    df[f'gcp-{i}'] = df.groupby('ID')['gcp'].shift(i)
print (df)
       ID  year  age  area  debt_ratio  gcp  gcp-1  gcp-2  gcp-3
0  654001  2013   49  East        0.14    0    NaN    NaN    NaN
1  654001  2014   50  East        0.17    0    0.0    NaN    NaN
2  654001  2015   51  East        0.23    1    0.0    0.0    NaN
3  654001  2016   52  East        0.18    0    1.0    0.0    0.0
4  112089  2013   39  West        0.13    0    NaN    NaN    NaN
5  112089  2014   40  West        0.15    0    0.0    NaN    NaN
6  112089  2015   41  West        0.18    1    0.0    0.0    NaN
7  112089  2016   42  West        0.21    1    1.0    0.0    0.0
```

More dynamic solution is get maximum number of groups and pass to `range`:

```
N = df['ID'].value_counts().max()

for i in range(1, N):
    df[f'gcp-{i}'] = df.groupby('ID')['gcp'].shift(i)
print (df)
       ID  year  age  area  debt_ratio  gcp  gcp-1  gcp-2  gcp-3
0  654001  2013   49  East        0.14    0    NaN    NaN    NaN
1  654001  2014   50  East        0.17    0    0.0    NaN    NaN
2  654001  2015   51  East        0.23    1    0.0    0.0    NaN
3  654001  2016   52  East        0.18    0    1.0    0.0    0.0
4  112089  2013   39  West        0.13    0    NaN    NaN    NaN
5  112089  2014   40  West        0.15    0    0.0    NaN    NaN
6  112089  2015   41  West        0.18    1    0.0    0.0    NaN
7  112089  2016   42  West        0.21    1    1.0    0.0    0.0
```

Comment: Hi again, thanks a lot! it worked perfectly! The dynamic solution is absolutely the best as my real data contains over 20 years data!